# How to hide Site Contents link using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, site-contents

I use SP 2013 on-premises and I am having a requirement to hide the `Site Contents` command/link.Is there any way I can achieve this with the help of PowerShell?
I tried with the SPSecurityTrimmedControl using SP D 2013, but it has a drawback,that we won't be  able to see the context menu for a  item within the document library.So that option is ruled out.

Comment: @SaMoIPP p What links you would want to hide? Any in particular like `Add page`

Comment: Benny,this is not a duplicate as I am looking for PowerShell solution.Please remove the duplicate in the question, if  you have rights.

Comment: Asad,Thanks for your reply.I need to hide the `Site Contents` link/command.Can i achieve through PowerShell

Comment: why not use CSS?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about the Quick launch menu try something like this:

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http://SharePoint/etc
$quicklaunch = $web.Navigation.QuickLaunch
$sc = $quicklaunch | where {$_.Title -eq 'Site Contents'}
$quicklaunch.Delete($sc)
```

Comment: Its not the quick launch.On the top right hand corner there exists the wheel symbol and on click of that the `Site Contents` site actions menu items would be populated.As part of my requirement , I need to hide the `Site Contents` menu item using PowerShell.

Comment: If I explain more clearly,for a particular SP group say `ABC Group` I want to hide this site contents page. ie, I should not  show this site contents link or `/15/layouts/viewlsts.aspx` page for this SPGroup.

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to use javascript / jquery. I don't think there is any way to do that in PS.